# Close Dropdown when I click outside dropdowns

Tags: json

When I selected dropdown, the selected list did not close quickly it will take a long time. how can solve this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking at the following JS, CSS and HTML snippets:

\\JS

```
document.addEventListener("click", toggleDropdown);

function toggleDropdown(event) {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");

    if (event.target.classList.contains('test')){
        dropdown.classList.toggle('show');
    } else {
        dropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
```

\\CSS

```
.dropdownMenu.show {
  overflow:visible;
  height:200px;
}
```

\\HTML

```
 <li id="products" class="products"><a href="#" class="test">Test</a>
                <ul id="dropdown" class="dropdownMenu">
                    <li><a href="#">test 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">test 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">test 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```